# How to get file contentType using file uploader in IE9

Tags: javascript, html, file-upload, content-type, fine-uploader

I'm trying to do a simple task. Upload a file with valums file uploader (or fine-uploader) with MVC3 application, save it in database, and let user download it again (with an action returning FileContentResult), but to do that, I need the contentType of file uploaded.

IE9 uses the "UploadHandlerForm" methods in vlaums file uploader (I'm using version 2.1.2), where I can't get the contentType.

When I'm using IE10 for example, the plugin uploads using UploadHandlerXhr, so I can get the content type and post it to the server, with that:

```
_upload: function(id, params)
{
    ...
    var file = this._files[id];
    var type = (file.fileSize != null ? file.fileSize : file.size);

    ....
    //and then, add it to be posted to server:
    xhr.setRequestHeader("X-File-Type", type);
}
```

Is there any way I cant get the contentType of the file from an input file with javascript in older browsers (like IE9)?

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what you are trying to do here at all.  Are you trying to send the content-type of the file in a separate request?  If so, why?  The content-type is part of each MPE request.  Just examine the Content-Type header of the multipart boundary that contains the file data.

Also, don't access variables/functions that start with an underscore.  Those are not part of the API and may change or be removed at any time.  In the future, I hope to prevent access to these internal entirely.

Comment: I'm just trying to get the content type of file in IE9 using valum file uploader (one of the most famous javascript plugins for assynchronous file upload, like attach a file to email while you write your message).
The upload request itself, comes with "multipart/form-data" as value for content-type in header. And the form submission has content-type: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"...

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of this. I maintain that uploader. As I mentioned, you can parse the content-type of the actual file by examining the content-type header of the multipart boundary (inside the request payload) that contains the file data. This should be very easy to do in virtually any server-side language. Have a look at the [server repo](https://github.com/Widen/fine-uploader-server) in the Github project for some examples. Also, the version of Fine Uploader is quite old. Consider upgrading